# What is the unix command to find out what executable file corresponds to a given command?

Tags: linux, unix, command-line

For example, if passed `ls` as input it should tell me that `/bin/ls` will run if run `ls` on the command-line.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### The command to use varies from shell to shell.

Only a shell built-in will tell one correctly what the shell will do for a given command name, since only built-ins can fully know about aliases, shell functions, other built-ins, and so forth.  Remember: Not all commands correspond to executable files in the first place.

- **For the Bourne Again shell, `bash`,** the built-in is the `type` command:

  ```
  $ type '['
  [ is a shell builtin
  ```
- **For the Fish shell, `fish`**, The `type` builtin works similarly to bash. To get just the path to an executable, use `command -v`:

  ```
  $ type cat
  cat is /bin/cat
  $ command -v cat
  /bin/cat
  ```
- **For the Korn Shell, `ksh`,** the built-in is the `whence` command — with `type` initially set up as an ordinary alias for `whence -v` and the `command` built-in with the `-v` option equivalent to `whence`:

  ```
  $ whence -v ls
  ls is a tracked alias for /bin/ls
  ```
- **For the Z Shell, `zsh`,** the built-in is the `whence` command, with the `command` built-in with the `-v` option equivalent to `whence` and the built-ins `type`, `which`, and `where` equivalent to `whence` with the options `-v`, `-c`, and `-ca` respectively.

  ```
  $ whence ls
  /bin/ls
  ```
- **For the T C Shell, `tcsh`,** the built-in is the `which` command — not to be confused with any external command by that name:

  ```
  > which ls
  ls: aliased to ls-F
  > which \ls
  /bin/ls
  ```

## Further reading

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/

Comment: Note that under ksh, "type" is a default alias for "whence -v" so can be used just like with traditional bourne shell and bash.

Comment: `type` is also builtin to zsh?

Comment: RHEL6's which RPM (e.g., `which-2.19-6.el6.x86_64`) puts a startup file in `/etc/profile.d/which2.sh`.  This is read by non-csh shells, including zsh.  It aliases `which` to itself.   So for zsh users in particular it overrides breaks the builtin `which`.

Answer (score 14):

You can use `which` for this:

```
aix@aix:~$ which ls
/bin/ls
```

It works by searching the `PATH` for executable files matching the names of the  arguments. Note that is does not work with shell aliases:

```
aix@aix:~$ alias listdir=/bin/ls
aix@aix:~$ listdir /
bin    dev   initrd.img      lib32   media  proc  selinux  tmp  vmlinuz
...
aix@aix:~$ which listdir
aix@aix:~$
```

`type`, however, does work:

```
aix@aix:~$ type listdir
listdir is aliased to `/bin/ls'
```

Comment: Be careful: if ls is a function or is aliased, you want 'type ls' rather than 'which ls'

Comment: `which` is not necessarily enough on its own. It only returns the **first** found *name* in $PATH ... That *name* may be a symbolic link, and *not* the actual *end-of-chain* executable.

Answer (score 8):

`which` does **not** (necessarily) return the executable file. It returns the first matching file **name** it finds in the $PATH (or multiple like named files when using `which -a`)... The **actual** executable may be multiple links away.

- `which locate`
  *`/usr/bin/locate`*
  `
- `file $(which locate)`
  *`/usr/bin/locate: symbolic link to /etc/alternatives/locate'`*

The command which finds the **actual** executable is `readlink -e`,
(in conjunction with `which`)

- `readlink -e $(which locate)`
  *`/usr/bin/mlocate`*

To see all the intermediate *links*:

```
f="$(which locate)"             # find name in $PATH
printf "# %s\n" "$f"
while f="$(readlink "$f")" ;do  # follow links to executable
    printf "# %s\n" "$f"
done

# /usr/bin/locate
# /etc/alternatives/locate
# /usr/bin/mlocate
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try:

```
whereis ls
```

It gives me:

```
ls: /bin/ls /usr/share/man/man1/ls.1.gz
```